# PHP 8.1.2 realpath returning false

Tags: php

I am currently upgrading my PHP website from 7.4 to 8.1.2 but I'm having an issue with 'realpath'. No matter what directory I put in the variable '$install_folder' just shows as false. It's bizarre as I tested this on my PHP 7.4 website and the code works as it should.

```
$install_folder = realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../../');
```

I have tried to cheese the fix by:

```
$dir = __DIR__; 
$install_folder = realpath($dir . '/../../../');
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Is the change from 7.4 to 8.0 the _only_ change, i.e. replacing like for like on the same server, or is this a new server which might have other system differences? Some general information about the server would be useful as well, e.g. Linux vs Windows, where on the server the code is running.

Comment: I do all my changes locally. If I change the PHP version to 7.4 the website boots up as normal. I have upgraded composer and all the required packages. There are also no errors within the logs or command line

Comment: "Locally" doesn't tell me much. "Locally" could mean a Windows laptop, a Linux server in your cupboard, a Docker container, a Virtual Machine, etc, etc.

Comment: Apologies. I'm using Windows 11 and is hosted using IIS

Comment: What do you get if you do: `var_dump(is_dir(__DIR__ . '/../../../'))`? Does it work if you simply remove the function `realpath()` and use the path `__DIR__ . '/../../../'` directly in your application?

Answer (score 0):

Is the php cli interpreter installed on your system?  On Debian/Ubuntu based systems this is the phpX-cli package.

IF the cli package is installed, I'd want to see the output of a test script that might shed some light on things.

```
#/path/to/php8

$dir = __DIR__;
echo $dir;
$install_folder = realpath($dir);
echo $install_folder;
```

Run this script as a regular user, and then as the user running the web site.

Comment: The output I recieve is - C:\Users\myname\Fork\WebsiteDirectory\Path1\Path2\Path3 ###
C:\Users\myname\Fork\WebsiteDirectory\Path1\Path2\Path3 ###

Within my code, the real path should return as C:\Users\myname\Fork\WebsiteDirectory

Comment: And the Path1\Path2\Path3 parts are in your control and part of your install package?  If yes, can you just truncate that off and not try to manipulate the path as you have in  your original?

Comment: I understand that you're just trying to help out, which is very good, but answers should be solutions and not contain follow up questions and partial debugging help. If you need to more info, or suggest how to debug it, that should be written as a comment instead. If you don't have enough rep to comment, you need to work on that first by answering answerable questions.

Comment: I managed to fix the issue. It was due to one of my folders having different permission settings. Weird how it worked on the older version of PHP but not the newest one.

Comment: @Hughesey I'm having this exact same issue, which folders/permissions did you change?